# HTML/CSS Inline-Block no float Divs within divs

Tags: html, css-float, displaytag, css

I have 3 DIVs within a DIV. The boxes will have an image. Currently they are image placeholders for future.

I would like to use `display: inline-block;` to line them up on the same line. For some reason they are still vertical instead of horizontal. I do not want to use `float` as I feel float should be used elsewhere.

HTML:

```
<div class="quickboxes">
  <div id="box1"><img name="" src="" width="75" height="75" alt="">1</div>
  <div id="box2"><img name="" src="" width="75" height="75" alt="">2</div>
  <div id="box3"><img name="" src="" width="75" height="75" alt="">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.quickboxes {
    display: inline-block;
}

#box1 {
    width: auto;
}

#box2 {
    width: auto;
}

#box3 {
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display:inline-block; needs to be in the css for the image divs, not the containing div.

Comment: This fixed it. Interesting, I thought you wanted the parent div to apply it. Thank you for your help. Any suggestions on how to space the child divs evenly? As 'margin:0 auto;' does nothing.

Comment: Change width:auto; on your image divs to be width:33%;

Comment: Awesome Thanks for your help. I actually used align-text:center but I had a feeling that would backfire later. 

Width:33% worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Add the rule:

```
#box1, #box2,#box3 {
display:inline-block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TBpXW/)**

In order for the boxes to be in row, you also have to set the inline-block property on them, not just  the parent container (which you probably don't need anyway).

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to avoid using `inline-block` is to use floats. 
Float them to the left and clear the floats in each `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you include inline-block in both as shown:

```
.quickboxes {
    display: inline-block;
}
#box1, #box2,#box3 {
display:inline-block;
}
```

And to center these boxes

```
.quickboxes {
    display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: -50%; /*- is important for outer div*/
}
#box1,#boc2,#box3{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 50%; /* + is important for inner div*/
}
```